# Codeigniter - Form validation not works

Tags: forms, codeigniter, validation

I already try to googling but not solve, my code below is to check duplicate before insert, when "tagnumber" field already exists will go to specific page and not inserted to table, it works but the problem is although not insert to the table but it wont go to specific page I want.

**below is my problem on conditional statements:**
if data **exists** on form validation will execute not insert the data.
 
if data **not exists** form validation will execute insert data but go to wrong page (same page with exists data page).

**my controoler :**

```
function tambahSubmit()
{

$tagnumber = $this->input->post("tagnumber");
$this->myigniter_model->addData($tagnumber); 
$this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
$this->load->library('form_validation');

// field name, error message, validation rules
$this->form_validation->set_rules('tagnumber', 'tagnumber', 'trim|required|is_unique[inventorytag.tagnumber]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('date', 'date', 'trim|required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('employee', 'employee', 'trim|required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('semnumber', 'semnumber', 'trim|required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('quantity', 'quantity', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('area', 'area', 'trim|required');



if($this->form_validation->run() == false)
{

    $this->load->view('YearEndStock/tampilan_input_gagal');
}
else
{

    $this->myigniter_model->addData($tagnumber);

    $this->load->view('YearEndStock/tampilan_input_sukses');


}
}
```

**my model :**

```
function addData($tagnumber)
{
  // Added $this->db->escape() and limit 1 for Performance
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT tagnumber FROM inventorytag WHERE tagnumber = ".$this->db->escape($tagnumber)." limit 1");

$data = array(      
'tagnumber' => $this->input->post('tagnumber'), 
'date'=> date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
'employee' => $this->input->post('employee'),
'semnumber' => $this->input->post('semnumber'), 
'quantity' => $this->input->post('quantity'), 
'area' => $this->input->post('area') 
);

return $query->num_rows() == 0 ? $this->db->insert('inventorytag', $data) : false;
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to do, you already added the code in the else part 

$this->myigniter_model->addData($tagnumber);

before the form validation 

$this->myigniter_model->addData($tagnumber);

Comment: if insert is already done then is_unique[inventorytag.tagnumber] validation fails and not get the success page

Comment: I added  code in the else part $this->myigniter_model->addData($tagnumber); before the form validation $this->myigniter_model->addData($tagnumber) because tagnumber check first whether already exists or not, if exists will not insert

Comment: I already remove  is_unique[inventorytag.tagnumber] but it still wont go to success page, i already set field structure on table for tagnumber ( not unique) and primarry key

Comment: Where is your is_unique callback? or the condition

Answer (score 0):

Then you just need to separate your true statement. Remove your is_unique validation.

```
if($this->form_validation->run() == false)
{
    SHOW ERRORS
    $this->load->view('YearEndStock/tampilan_input_gagal');
}
else
{
    $row = $this->db->get_where('inventorytag', array('tagnumber' => $tagnumber))->row();

    if (empty($row)) {
    //insert
    $this->myigniter_model->addData($tagnumber);
    } else {
    //row exists
    }

    $this->load->view('YearEndStock/tampilan_input_sukses');


}
```

Comment: I'm sorry It still wont appear success page, My table structure for "tagnumber" field is as primmary key and not unique , is that right ?

Comment: is have relation with .htaccess file ? because some article is review that , i already try to change .htaccess but it still not works